# Select first option (value="") of select box when cloned

Tags: jquery

I'm using codes below to set **value** attributes to **null** but they only work for `input` fields. How can I do same thing for select boxes? When I clone, the first option (Select unit) should be selected.

**VER 1:**

```
var $cloned = $('#unit-field-cover div:last').clone();
$('#unit-field-cover div:last').after($cloned);
$('#unit-field-cover div:last select').attr({name:"size-unit[]", value:''});
```

**HTML**

```
<select name="size-unit[0]">
      <option value="">Select unit</option>
      <option value="Inches" selected="selected">Inches</option>
      <option value="Centimeters" >Centimeters</option>
      <option value="N/a">N/a</option>
</select>
```

Comment: trying to change the attribute won't change the value property

Comment: Please use the search before you ask a new question.

Comment: I did but couldn't find exact answer. Maybe didn't use proper keywords.

Comment: I searched for `[jquery] select first option` .

Comment: Anyway, thanks for - vote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `val()`:

```
$('#unit-field-cover div:last select').val("");
```

[**FIDDLE EXAMPLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ehsansajjad465/9hVBe/)

Comment: Thank you It worked. I'll accept it 8 minutes later.